# Uniqueness of the limit of a function for Hausdorff spaces that are not metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is there a proof to show that a mapping from an arbitrary topological space to an arbitrary Hausdorff space (excluding metric spaces) has a unique limit point? Therefore, the only properties to be used are:

1) inverse continuous mappings of open sets are open sets

2) any two points in a Hausdorff space can have disjoint open neighborhoods

3) any point in a Hausdorff space is a close set

Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of "limit point of a mapping"?

Comment: I think the OP means an (existing) limit of $f$ at some point $x$. An wants to know why the "an" could be replaced by "the" in case of Haussdorfness of the target of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a general topological space, the appropriate notion of convergence rely on the notion of *filter base*.

Let $X$ a set. A filter $F$ on $X$ is a set of non-empty subsets of $X$ such that $A,B\in F$ implies $A\cap B\in F$, and $A\in F$ and $A'\subseteq A$ implies $A'\in F$. A *filter base* on $X$ is a set $F$ of non empty subsets of $X$ such that for each $A,B\in F$, there exists $C\in F$ such that $C\subseteq A\cap B$. (In particular $A\cap B\not=\varnothing$.) Note that a filter is a base filter. (The reciprocal is false in general.)

If $X$ is a topological space and if $x_0\in X$, the set $V(x_0)$ of neighbourhoods of $x_0$ in $X$ is a filter. Any fundamental system of neighbourhoods of $x_0$ in $X$ is a filter base on $X$.

If $X$ is a topological space, if $Y\subseteq X$ and if $x_0 \in \overline{Y}$, then the set $F_{x_0}(Y)$ of subsets of $Y$ of the form $Y\cap V$ where $V$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $X$ is a filter on $Y$. ($Y\cap V\not=\varnothing$ especially because $x_0 \in \overline{Y}$.) If $Y = X$ you recover the previous definition.

The more general case of *limit of a function* is the following : let $X$ be a set and $F$ a filter base on $X$, and $f : X\rightarrow Y$ a map where $Y$ is a topological space, and $l\in Y$. One says that $f$ *tends to* $l$ *along* $F$ if for each neighbourhood $V$ of $l$ in $Y$, there exists a $B\in F$ such that $f(B)\subseteq V$. Then, we have the unicity theorem :

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a set and $F$ a filter base on $X$, and $f : X\rightarrow Y$ a map where $Y$ is an Hausdorff topological space, such that $f$ has a limit along $F$. Then this limit is unique

*Proof* Let $l,l'\in Y$ be limits of $f$ along $F$. As $Y$ is Hausdorff, you can find two neighbourhoods $V$ resp. $V'$ of $l$ resp. $l'$ in $Y$ such that $V\cap V'= \varnothing$. Then there exists $B,B'\in F$ such that $f(B)\subseteq V$ and $f(B')\subseteq V'$. As $F$ is a filter base, there is a $B''\in F$ included in $B\cap B'$, then $f(B'')\subseteq V\cap V'$. As $B''\not=\varnothing$ (an filter is constitued of non-empty sets...) necessarily $V\cap V'\not= \varnothing$, a contradiction.

Now, take $X = Y = \mathbf{R}$. Thanks to the previous notions, we can handle the following notions in the same way, thanks to (different filter bases) :

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)$ (this nototion is used in the definition of continuity at $x_0$)
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0, x\not = x_0} f(x)$ (this notion is used in the definition of limit of a fucntion at some point)

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) = l$ means that $f$ as limit $l$ along the filter (a filter is a filter base, remember) $V(x_0)$, whereas $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0, x\not = x_0} f(x) = l$ means that $f$ has limit $l$ along the filter base $F_{x_0}(Y)$ with $Y = \mathbf{R}\backslash\{x_0\}$. (These are in fact *definitions*)

Last remark : $x_0 = 0$ and if $f$ is the map equal to zero on $Y$ and $1000$ at $x_0$, one should take care of the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)$ does not exist *because* $f$ si not continuous at $x_0$, whereas $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0, x\not = x_0} f(x)$ does and is equal to $0$.

Comment: Btw, remark that this proof is valid for metric spaces as well. 
*Haussorfness is NOT a metric property, but a topological one*, as it simply means that the diagonal in the fiber product $X\times_Y X$ is *closed* (topological property) in the fiber product $X\times_Y X$. (Here I noted $f : X\rightarrow Y$ the map.) The fiber product $X\times_Y X$ is just the subset of $X\times X$ consisting in couples $(x,x')$ such that $f(x) = f(x')$.

Comment: How does the fact that "As $l,l'$ are limits of $f$ at a point $x$" show that "you can find a neighbourhood $U$ (resp. $U'$) of $x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$ (resp. $f(U')\subseteq V'$)."?

Comment: By definition, $f : X \rightarrow Y$ converges to $l\in Y$ at $x\in X$ if and only if for each neighbourhood $V$ of $l$ in $Y$ there exists a neighboorhoud $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$. Think of same definition it the case where $X = Y = \mathbf{R}$ with the usual topology...

Comment: Here is a counter example. Consider the mapping $f : [-1,1] \rightarrow R$and $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x \not= 0$ and $f(0) = 1000$. Then as $x \rightarrow 0$ $f(x) \rightarrow 1000$ and so 1000 is a limit point. But no open neighbourhood of $0$ can be mapped to a subset of the point 1000.

Comment: What you have stated is the condition that $f$ is continuous. In this case it need not be continuous.

Comment: First of all, I have stated the definition of a function converging to $l$ as $x'$ tends to $x$. Second : you counter-example is not a counter-example, as $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. In your example, if the limit you assert would be true, $f$ would be continuous (because by definition continuity at $0$ means that $f(x)\rightarrow f(0)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$) but as you said, $f$ is not continuous...

Comment: Yes I agree I made a mistake and $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ in my example. However, we note that $f(x) = 1000$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $V$ be any open neighborhood of the limit point $0$. Then it is not true that for all $V$ we can find $U$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. For example, let $V$ = $(-1, 1)$. Since $x \in U$ and hence $f(x) = 1000 \in f(U)$, $f(U)$ is not a subset of $V$.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're talking about. You keep talking about $U$ in your previous comment, and you use $U$ everywhere, but you've never defined it anywhere, and you're showing nothing, just asserting. Anyway, I gave you the definition of a limit, and a proof that $l=l'$, and showed that your counter-example wasn't a counter example. What else remains unclear to you ?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should be clearer. Let's start from your definition. You mentioned that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ converges to $l \in Y$ at $x \in X$ iff for each nbhd $V$ of $l$ in $Y$ there exists a nbhd $U$ of $x$ in $X$ s.t. $f(U) \subset V$. Let's consider the simpler function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \not= 0$ and $f(0) = 1000$. The limit point $l$ of $f$ at $x=0$ is thus $0$. I want to show that even though  $f: X \rightarrow Y$ converges to $l=0 \in Y$ at $x=0 \in X$, there exists some nbhd $V$ of $l=0$ in $Y$ s.t. $f(U)$ is not a subset of $V$, for all open nbhd $U$ of $x=0$. Do you agree?

Comment: Now, consider the open nbhd $V = (-1,1)$. We want to show that $f(U)$ is not a subset of $V = (-1,1)$ for all open nbhd  $U$ of $x=0$. Since $f(0)=1000$, $1000 \in f(U)$ for all open nbhd $U$ of $x=0$. Since $1000$ is not an element of $V = (-1,1)$, $f(U)$ cannot be a subset of $V$. Hence, your definition for a limit is not correct.

Comment: Is my example clear enough or is there something wrong with it? I think your definition works if (keeping everything else in your definition), we change the last part to $g(U) \in V$ instead of $f(U) \in V$. $g : X \rightarrow Y$ is an auxiliary function defined such that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \not= q$, where $q \in X$ is the point we want to find the limit point at, and $g(x) = l$ when $x = q$. $l$ is the limit point.

Comment: That is perfect.

Comment: But your proof for my question won't work then.

Comment: I will delete it then, and rewrite differently

Comment: @LateLearner Updated. All apologies as I was vague. You was right !

Comment: @Olórin Is this a generalization of the fact that a sequence $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to Y$ has at most one limit if $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: In particular, is there a "natural" filter for $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, the natural one is the one used for defining what the limits when $n\to +\infty$ of for instance a sequence of real number $(u_n)_n$ is ; it is the filter of cofinite (that is, set of finite complementary set) subsets of $\mathbf{N}$. Naturally you can define anologue filters to the ones I mentions in my answer, to define what the limit of a sequence is at a number $n_0$, but as you may guess, they are not very interested dued to the discrete character of $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: Also, all these filters are "traces" on $\mathbf{N}$ of analogue "natural" filters on $\mathbf{R}$.